# Getting junk values extra while reading binary file iOS

Tags: ios, swift, hex

While reading binary files, there is an extra junk values are coming. Binary file contains list of hex values. There are some extra values I am seeing in results. the below image is the output from xcode console. extra values are inside the blue color rectangle.

[image: Console screenshot]

Original values in file :

[image: Original values]

The below code is used to read the data from file :

```
var archieveData = Data()
let documents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString

let filePath = documents.strings(byAppendingPaths: ["test.bin"])[0]
let data = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: filePath)
archieveData = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: data!, requiringSecureCoding: false)
let hexString = archieveData.hexDescription
let hexArr = hexString.components(withLength: 32)
   print("hex string \(hexArr)")
```

Extensions to convert into hex values and split array into string

```
extension Data {
    var hexDescription : String{
        return reduce("") {$0+String(format: "%02x", $1)}
    }
}

extension String {
    func components(withLength length: Int) -> [String] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: length).map {
            let start = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: $0)
            let end = self.index(start, offsetBy: length, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex
            return String(self[start..<end])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `archieveData` contains the *archive* of the data. Of course that is different from the data itself. It is a “binary property list” starting with the magic bytes 62 70 6c 69 73 74 30 30 for “bplist”.

Comment: Why do you need this step: `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: data!, requiringSecureCoding: false)`?